# Java applet access to environment variables

Tags: java, applet

We have a (signed) Java Applet which reads and read for years an environment variable (Windows same under Linux) to load a library.

Now suddenly this seems no more possible. Has anybody also made this experience? Is there a change of security policies which now denies reading such variables for applets? Any documentation?

So without changing the applet it doesn't work any more...

Comment: Edit the Java Console output into your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a signed applet? Check the validity. In the folowing example of code:

```
 keytool -genkey -alias sickpea -validity 3650 -dname \
    "CN=Sickpea, OU=Engineering, O=Sickpea, L=San Francisco, S=CA, C=US"
$ keytool -selfcert -alias sickpea -validity 3650
```

the valididy is set to 10 years.

With:

```
jarsigner -verbose -certs -verify myApplet.jar
```

you can verify the validity.